# Can "earlier this year" be used with past progressive?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-tense

I am struggling with the correct tense for the following sentence:

> Some of you might know me already as I **was interning** for six months at this company earlier this year.

Since "earlier this year" refers to a *specific* point in the past, past tense comes to mind. However, "for six months" indicates a longer-lasting activity, requiring the progressive form of the past tense. Is my train of thought correct or do I need to use another tense for this sentence?

Comment: I don't see why 'earlier this year' can't refer to a period of time as well as a specific date. If it worries you, you could always say "I was an intern for six months".

Comment: "I interned" is fine: simple past tense is often used with completed past events that last for a period of time, e.g. "I travelled for six months", "I believed for years". If you're discussing something that happened at one point during that period, past continuous might be more appropriate ("I met you when I was interning here"). I don't think it's a big issue though, and past continuous wouldn't be wrong, just longer.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the tense you used. You could also use different tenses.